# A medium-agnostic word for a readthrough/playthrough/viewing?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, nouns, mass-media

Is there a word analogous to “readthrough” that works regardless of what kind of media it is?

That is, I’m looking to condense “an instance of going through an entire (fictional) work” down to a noun (or a shorter noun phrase). (It doesn’t have to be specific to fiction media.)

*Readthrough* makes sense for a novel or comic book; *playthrough* for a video game; and *viewing* for a movie. I’m not sure if there’s anything natural for listening to an audiobook or podcast, or for watching a tv series.

The usage is like: “I’m in the middle of a *Discworld* *readthrough* right now.” or “I picked up so many more clues on the second *viewing*!” or “I do a *playthrough* every year.”

Note: This is distinct from a single “session” of reading/consuming the media-item. A readthrough-thing can contain many sessions of actually reading/watching/playing.

Generic terms I’ve considered:

- A “usage” of the media is a bit strange even if the use/purpose of media is to engage with it.
- A “binge” is almost what I’m looking for, but implies that you’re completing the playthrough/thing in one session. And notice that you often see it as “binge-watch” or “binge-read” to clarify the medium (and distinguish it from binge-eating/etc.)
- An “experience” seems too generic; nothing to specify it as about media.
- A “consumption” is really close, but I find it unnatural to use as a countable noun — “a consumption; many consumptions”.

Is there anything more fitting that I’ve missed? (Poetic/archaic phrasing is acceptable!)

Comment: What's the difference between a readthrough and just reading a book, or a playthrough vs playing to the end? Is there some subtlety, e.g. speed or thoroughness? ([runthrough](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/run-through) means a quick and cursory go).

Comment: Got an answer? Post an answer.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest (from [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/review))

> **review** *verb* (WRITE/TALK ABOUT)
> If critics review a book, play, film, etc. they write their opinion of it.

Neither 'readthrough' nor 'playthrough' have significant coverage in mainstream dictionaries.

> I’m in the middle of a Discworld review right now.
> I do a review every year.

Comment: This word doesn't fit. A person doing a readthrough, playthrough, or viewing of a piece of media does not have to write or talk about it.

Comment: @user2357112 they don't *have* to be writing about it. [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/review) has *to view or see again, to examine or study again, to go over or examine critically or deliberately.*

Comment: That's a different sense of the word than the definition you quoted, and that sense of the word doesn't fit either - "readthrough", "playthrough", and "viewing" all apply the *first* time you consume a piece of media.

Comment: @user2357112 OP says “I picked up so many more clues **on the second viewing**!” or “I do a playthrough **every year**.” I have no idea what the fictional words "readthrough" or "playthrough" mean.

Comment: If you don't know what words mean, then don't try to suggest synonyms! And the fact that an example sentence said "second viewing" doesn't mean that all viewings have to be second or later - after all, what about the *first* viewing?

Comment: @user2357112 the question *says* what they are intended to mean, which is obviously not just the first time.

Comment: Sure, it's not *just* the first time, but your definition *excludes* the first time. Also, "playthrough" is [in the dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/playthrough).

Comment: @user2357112 that definition does not support your claim. May I suggest that instead of posting your invaluable opinion under every answer, you post a better one?

Comment: It sounds like you may have misread my comment as saying the words in the question *only* apply the first time someone consumes a piece of media. I did not say "only". They apply to the first, second, third, etc. times. A word that means "to view or see *again*" does not fit.

Answer (score 2):

If a verb is acceptable, you could use **to plow through**, defined by [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/plow-through) as:

> to finish reading, eating, or dealing with something with difficulty

It is most often used with books, but (as the above definition suggests) one can certainly use it with other media.

Comment: This carries too many implications about the intensity of the activity to be a good fit.

Answer (score 0):

How about "redo" or "do-over"? Not sure if a hyphenated spelling of the second one makes it conforming to your requirements.

Comment: This doesn't fit. "Readthrough", "playthrough", and "viewing" all apply for the first time a person consumes a piece of media. "Redo" and "do-over" do not. Plus, it would be very strange to speak of "redoing" a movie or book to mean watching or reading it; it sounds more like producing a remaster or remake.

Answer (score -1):

"[Consumption](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/consumption)",

> … mysteries, which she consumes for fun …

"[experiencing](https://:%20something%20personally%20encountered,%20undergone,%20or%20lived%20through)",

> the act or process of directly perceiving events or reality

"[digesting](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/digesting)",

> to take into the mind or memory

"[going through](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/go-through)"?

> Let’s go through it once more to make sure you know what to say.

The answer is based on my own "sense of language" and dictionaries don't quite make it.

Comment: Please include sources and citations for your answer as well as how this answers the question.  I encourage you to see the [help].

Comment: The answer is based on my own "sense of language". No academic source is going to contain remarks like "fits for all possible media". On the other hand, if you try to use these with different media, you immediately understand if these fit or don't. But! If you know how to add relevant sources here, I will appreciate you doing this.

Comment: Again I encourage you to [edit] your post after viewing the [help].  Here is a list of resources that you may prefer to cite https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2573/36710